# Value Counts of Column Slice to Contain All Possible Unique Values in Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
group   val
A       1
A       1
A       2
B       1
B       2
B       3
```

I want to get the value_counts for each group separately, but want to show all possible values for each value_count group:

```
> df[df['group']=='A']['val'].value_counts()

1       2
2       1
3       NaN
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

But it currently looks like this:

```
> df[df['group']=='A']['val'].value_counts()

1       2
2       1
Name: val, dtype: int64
```

Any one know any way I can show value_counts with all possible values represented?

Comment: `df.groupby(df.index).value_counts()` doesn't work for you?

Comment: thanks-- i might not be implementing correctly, but im getting this error:
'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Comment: How about: `df.groupby(df.index).apply(lambda x: x['val'].value_counts())`?

Comment: Unfortunately no. This gives me the full 'val' column and a list of 1s in a second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [185]: df.groupby('group')['val'].value_counts().unstack('group')
Out[185]: 
group    A    B
val            
1      2.0  1.0
2      1.0  1.0
3      NaN  1.0

In [186]: df.groupby('group')['val'].value_counts().unstack('group')['A']
Out[186]: 
val
1    2.0
2    1.0
3    NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = StringIO("""group,val
A,1
A,1
A,2
B,1
B,2
B,3""")
df = pd.read_csv(data)

print(df, '\n')

res_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['group'].unique(), df['val'].unique()])
res = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(index=res_idx),
                 df.groupby('group').apply(lambda x: x['val'].value_counts())],
                axis=1)

print(res)
```

Produces:

```
  group  val
0     A    1
1     A    1
2     A    2
3     B    1
4     B    2
5     B    3 

     val
A 1  2.0
  2  1.0
  3  NaN
B 1  1.0
  2  1.0
  3  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ubuntu's one liner seems to work pretty straightforwardly!

Comment: Unutbu, not Ubuntu. The person is not an OS! :) Glad you found what you were looking for.